# Errors in installing octave in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: software-installation, octave

Whenever I run the command "sudo apt install octave" I keep getting this in my terminal window

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 libxml-libxml-perl amd64 2.0128+dfsg-1                                           
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 pstoedit amd64 3.70-1.1
  404  Not Found
Ign:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 tex-common all 6.05
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 texinfo amd64 6.1.0.dfsg.1-8
  404  Not Found
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 libosmesa6 amd64 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1
  404  Not Found
Ign:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 octave-common all 4.0.3-2ubuntu3
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 octave amd64 4.0.3-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found
Ign:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 octave-info all 4.0.3-2ubuntu3
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 tex-common all 6.05
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe i386 octave-common all 4.0.3-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe i386 octave-info all 4.0.3-2ubuntu3
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml-libxml-perl/libxml-libxml-perl_2.0128+dfsg-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pstoedit/pstoedit_3.70-1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tex-common/tex-common_6.05_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texinfo/texinfo_6.1.0.dfsg.1-8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libosmesa6_12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/octave/octave-common_4.0.3-2ubuntu3_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/octave/octave_4.0.3-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/octave/octave-info_4.0.3-2ubuntu3_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried using "fix missing" and that didn't work. Tried using update and I got this:

```
Ign:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease                                                                     
Get:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release [3,462 B]                                                             
Get:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release.gpg [801 B]                                                           
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                  
Err:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release.gpg                                                                   
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG D68FA50FEA312927 MongoDB 3.2 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                             
Ign:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease                                                                           
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease                                                                            
Ign:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                                                                                   
Ign:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease                                          
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                          
Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                     
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release                                                                             
  404  Not Found
Err:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily Release                                                                                       
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release                                                                                    
  404  Not Found
Err:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release                                                        
  404  Not Found
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:19 http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu trusty InRelease                  
Err:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release                                 
  404  Not Found
Err:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu yakkety Release                                 
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG D68FA50FEA312927 MongoDB 3.2 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key E1254F21D636B7EFDE41D2AF50E2BCF0E3805CD8 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 16.10 is no longer supported, and the PPA is missing a needed security feature (and therefore probably should have never worked).  The PPA will certainly not be updated.  Ubuntu 16.10 *will* not be.  You should first take steps to keep your computer secure by using a supported version of Ubuntu.

As soon as possible, you should upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 (run Software Updater) or install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS over your existing Ubuntu installation (this should preserve your home folder, but make backups).  You can stick with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS until April 2021, or you can update 17.10 to 18.04 LTS in April and stick with that until April 2023.

Octave is included in the Ubuntu repositories.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS contains v4.0.0, and Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 contain v4.2.1, which is the latest version.